# Whenever I use Environment preset, the 3d model is not appear & also the website break after some time

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-drei

I wrote this code :

```
 import React from 'react'
    import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
    import {Environment, Center } from '@react-three/drei'
    
    import Shirt from './Shirt'
    import Backdrop from './Backdrop'
    import CameraRig from './CameraRig'
    
    const index = () => {
      return (
        <Canvas
          shadows
          camera={{position: [0, 0, 0], fov : 25}}
          gl = {{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
          className='w-full max-w-full h-full transition-all ease-in'
        >
          <ambientLight intensity={0.5}/>
          <Environment preset='city' />
    
          <CameraRig>
            <Backdrop />
            <Center>
              <Shirt />
            </Center>
          </CameraRig>
        </Canvas>
      )
    }
    
    export default index
```

When I run this code, my 3d model doesn't appear on the page, and my full website is breaking after 5 to 10 seconds, But, whenever I comment out `<Environment preset='city' />`, my website is working but the background of my website is greyish, but I wanted it to be white to fully showcase my website
I'm using react three drei version 9.70.4